# How to get access to ETH/UNI pool in uniswap v3 on Goerli testnet?

Tags: pool, uniswap, ether

I want to get pool instance of ETH/UNI pool in Uniswap V3 on Goerli testnet.

I tried to pass WETH token address in Goerli to getPool() function, but it returns 0x0, which means that there is no such pool.
Also, I tried to get balance of WETH of my wallet address, but it also returns 0. I have some WETH, though.
I expect to get ETH/UNI pool and want to know exactly the relationship between ETH and WETH.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was that I used wrong WETH token address on Goerli.
I changed it from 0x0Bb7509324cE409F7bbC4b701f932eAca9736AB7 to 0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6.